# Reading data from dynamodb streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have setup streams for my dynamo tables. I was following the example program in the documentation for reading the data from the streams(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.LowLevel.Walkthrough.CompleteProgram.html). However I have a problem -
when iterating through the shards it seems like checking for a sharditerator to be null is not a sufficient condition to exit the loop. My code gets into an infinite loop. In the example program the number of changes is counted and that is used to exit the loop -->

```
while (nextItr != null && numChanges > 0) {

   // Use the iterator to read the data records from the shard

  GetRecordsResult getRecordsResult = 
          streamsClient.getRecords(new GetRecordsRequest().
          withShardIterator(nextItr));
   List<Record> records = getRecordsResult.getRecords();
   System.out.println("Getting records...");
   for (Record record : records) {
           System.out.println(record);
            numChanges--;
    }
    nextItr = getRecordsResult.getNextShardIterator();
}
```

But in a real environment I am sure maintaining the list of changes is not practical. Is the design meant to be an infinite loop? Why does the shardIterator not become null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm repeating my answer to the same question you posted on [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=211314&tstart=0) here:

The nextIterator will not become null as long as the shard is open and is actively receiving possible future updates. Once the shard closes and the last record has been traversed, then your loop could exit and indicate there it is no longer possible to get more records from the shard.

Please refer to our documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/GetRecordsResult.html#getNextShardIterator()

"If set to null, the shard has been closed and the requested iterator will not return any more data."

Hope that helps, thanks for your interest in DynamoDB!

Comment: Thanks. But what is the best way to exit this loop while reading a stream? I resorted to checking if the number of records are 0 and then exit the loop. But I was wondering of the possibility of there being empty shards in between the stream.

Comment: There is definitely a possibility of more records even after receiving a getRecords result of 0. How can you be sure no more records can come into your active stream if the stream is still opened for writing? The only way for you to be sure is to disable the stream so you know for sure no more records can come in, then iterate through the records until nextIterator is null. Otherwise, the point of an open stream is that you should always be polling for more records because records may show up again as long as the stream is open.

Comment: So is there any way to close the shard X, create new one Y (in order to store new possible changes in DynamoDB) and read all changes till certain period from shard X?