# Reading AWS Dynamodb Stream

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I want to do an incremental DynamoDB backup on S3 using DynamoDB Streams. I have a lambda that reads the dynamodb stream and writes files into S3. In order to mark already read shards I have ExclusiveStartShardId logged into configuration file.

What I do is:

1. Describe the stream (using the logged ExclusiveStartShardId)
2. Get stream's shards
3. For all shards that are **CLOSED** (has EndingSequenceNumber) I do the following:

   - Get shard iterator for the certain shard (shardIteratorType: 'TRIM_HORIZON')
   - Iterate through shard and fetch records till NextShardIterator becomes null

The problem here is that I read only closed shards and in order to get new records I must wait (undetermined-amount-of-time) for it to be closed.

It seems that the last shard is usually in **OPEN** state (has **NO** EndingSequenceNumber). If I remove the check for EndingSequenceNumber from the pseudo code above I end up with infinite loop because when I hit the last shard NextShardIterator is always presented. I cannot also do a check if fetched items are 0 because there could be "gaps" in the shard.

In this tutorial **numChanges** is used in order to stop the infinite loop http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.LowLevel.Walkthrough.html#Streams.LowLevel.Walkthrough.Step5

What is the best approach in this situation?

I also found a similar question: [Reading data from dynamodb streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912168/reading-data-from-dynamodb-streams). Unfortunately I could not find the answer for my question.

Comment: Have you set up the DynamoDB stream as an event source for your Lambda function?  From your description it almost sounds like you are trying to do the polling of the stream yourself.

Comment: The event source for my lambda is Scheduled Event: hourevent (it is executed every hour). When the lambda is executed I am trying to read the stream from some "checkpoint" and backup the new data.

Answer (score 2):

Why not attach the DynamoDB stream as an event source for your Lambda function? Then Lambda will take care of polling the stream and calling your function when necessary.  See [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) for details.

Comment: But that way the Lambda function will be executed on every data modification in DynamoDB. That means I should create many backup files even the batch size is big / or I should read and then write file on s3 which is expensive and time consuming operation.

Comment: You can control the batch size up to a max of 10000.  So your Lambda function would not necessarily be called for every modification.

Comment: But as far as I know lambda is called on every modification/insert and batch size is used when two or more modification occurred at the same time. In other words if you have modification/insert in 10 seconds and batch size 100 lambda function would be executed in 10 seconds (ignoring batch size).

Comment: @garnaat How often does Lambda poll the DynamoDB Stream. Can that value be configured?

Comment: Might be easy (and a good idea) to start with Lambda but gets a lot more expensive at scale.